# Empty div not displaying JavaScript output? (... at least I think that's the issue)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to coding & I also haven't practiced these languages in a while, so this might be a really dumb question. I'm trying to make a random generator using [this](http://www.name-generators.com/name-generators/how-to-make-name-generator.htm) tutorial, but I've run into some issues with finishing the project.

My JavaScript is

```
function generator() {

  var ideas = ["design it for meerkats", "make it twice as big and half as loud", "use the rainbow filter in photoshop", "design using sound", "must not have a conscious or unconscious gender bias", "make it appeal to dogs", "make it so it can be unmade"];

  var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * ideas.length);

  var command = ideas[randomNumber1];

  //alert(command);

};


//generator();

 if(document.getElementById("result")){
 document.getElementById("placeholder").removeChild(document.getElementById("result"));
  }
  //A div element is created to show the generated name.
  //The Name is added as a textnode. Textnode is added to the placeholder.
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.setAttribute("id", "result");
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(command));
  document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(element);
```

and my HTML is

```
<body onload=”generator()”>
    <div id="generator">
        <div id="placeholder"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Click here!" onclick="generator()" />
    </div>
```

In the tutorial (and on the demo) the randomly generated text shows up in in the "placeholder" div. However, when I try to run the code the text never shows up, just the button, which does nothing when clicked. I've gone back over the tutorial a bunch of times & I feel like I must be missing something really obvious.

Comment: This is pretty simple, but your quotes in the example above are curly braces. Did you copy/paste them? `onload=”generator()”>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the quotes being curly brackets? They're showing up as quotes to me.

Comment: There are multiple types of quotes. You want to use `'` or `"`; but you are using `”`. Visually, they often look the same, but they are not the same character. That will cause your code to fail.

Answer (score 6):

The code that places the the text in the div is outside of the `generator` function. This is the function that is called when the button is clicked

```
function generator() {

  var ideas = ["design it for meerkats", "make it twice as big and half as loud", "use the rainbow filter in photoshop", "design using sound", "must not have a conscious or unconscious gender bias", "make it appeal to dogs", "make it so it can be unmade"];

  var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * ideas.length);

  var command = ideas[randomNumber1];

  if(document.getElementById("result")){
   document.getElementById("placeholder").removeChild(document.getElementById("result"));
  }
  //A div element is created to show the generated name.
  //The Name is added as a textnode. Textnode is added to the placeholder.
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.setAttribute("id", "result");
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(command));
  document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Hi Musa! I moved that section so that it's inside the generator function, but the text still isn't showing up in the div. If you have any other ideas I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Try replacing all this fancy quotes with regular double quotes.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys! I fixed those curly quotes, but there's still nothing appearing in the div. The only thing I can come up with is that .getElementById("result") isn't working because there's nothing in the HTML with that "result" id. I looked at the demo, though, and it doesn't seem to be an issue there, so maybe I'm just making stuff up. How would I go about fixing that, if that is the issue?